# KeyError: 'found' on Elastic2DocManager when syncing data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, synchronization

From MongoDB to Elastic Search(5.6.5), I sync the database with Mongo-Connector using Elastic2DocManager:

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager
```

After seeing some update on docs.deleted of mongodb_meta on Elastic Search:

```
health status index             uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   mongodb_meta      3wd6OjTT6tD3f6ZGezZw   5   1    1337173         8372    192.9mb        192.9mb
```

mongo-connector stops working with below error:

```
2018-07-11 07:16:41,977 [WARNING] elasticsearch:97 - POST http://localhost:9200/_bulk [status:N/A request:10.003s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
Exception in thread Thread-1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\doc_managers\elastic2_doc_manager.py", line 150, in run
        self._docman.send_buffered_operations()
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\doc_managers\elastic2_doc_manager.py", line 482, in send_buffered_operations
        action_buffer = self.BulkBuffer.get_buffer()
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\doc_managers\elastic2_doc_manager.py", line 696, in get_buffer
        self.update_sources()
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\util.py", line 35, in wrapped
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\doc_managers\elastic2_doc_manager.py", line 628, in update_sources
        if ES_doc['found']:
    KeyError: 'found'
```

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the versions are compatible.
- The required python packages are installed, this is my requirements.txt look like.

  ```
  astroid==1.6.5
  autopep8==1.3.5
  certifi==2018.8.24
  elasticsearch==6.3.1
  elasticsearch-dsl==6.2.1
  isort==4.3.4
  lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
  mccabe==0.6.1
  pycodestyle==2.4.0
  pylint==1.9.2
  pymongo==3.7.1
  rope==0.11.0
  six==1.11.0
  urllib3==1.23
  wrapt==1.10.11
  ```